# Docker vfs as default storage driver for docker 1.10.0

Tags: docker

I have just installed version 1.10.0 of docker using the following on ubuntu 12.04

```
apt-get install -y docker-engine
```

See info here:

```
root@noel:/var/lib/docker/vfs/dir# docker info                       
Containers: 6                                                        
 Running: 3                                                          
 Paused: 0                                                           
 Stopped: 3                                                          
Images: 64                                                           
Server Version: 1.10.0                                               
Storage Driver: vfs                                                  
Execution Driver: native-0.2                                         
Logging Driver: json-file                                            
Plugins:                                                             
 Volume: local                                                       
 Network: bridge null host                                           
Kernel Version: 3.13.0-76-generic                                    
Operating System: Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS                                 
OSType: linux                                                        
Architecture: x86_64                                                 
CPUs: 1                                                              
Total Memory: 490 MiB                                                
Name: noel                                                           
ID: RODV:3KVW:TCQC:7SMO:43T3:J7XZ:NWMT:K2GB:FE3Z:N3BV:X5FS:V5DC      
WARNING: No swap limit support
```

After running some containers - graphite, grafana most of my disk space is used up here:

```
root@noel:/var/lib/docker/vfs/dir# du -hs          
33G
```

Am I doing something wrong here?

i.e Do I need to override the default storage driver.

Never had this issue with space with previous versions which I believe was devicemapper by default

.

Comment: I'm guessing it has more to do with old container volumes using up space. You can use the new "docker volume" commands to see and clean these out.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure, in addition of volumes, that you don't have old exited container or intermediate images:

```
docker rm $(docker ps -qa --no-trunc --filter "status=exited")
docker rmi $(docker images --filter "dangling=true" -q --no-trunc)
```

The, as suggested, use [`docker volume ls`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/volume_ls/) and [`docker volume inspect`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/volume_inspect/) to check for volume space.

Answer (score 0):

I changed to using 14.04 where I could install Linux image extras as outlined in docker installation page.

This allows you to use aufs as the storage driver which from reading the documentation is the preferred option for ubuntu.

See https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/storagedriver/selectadriver/

Regarding my issue with vfs, I bought up a vagrant box, installed docker, built my images and started my containers(3) and there was 33G used and all in the docker vfs directory.
So I dont believe I have old volumes or containers hanging around